# Razorpay callbacks in android fragment is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, fragment

Razorpay callbacks is not working in fragment instead of activity using fragment please give a solution If anyone aware thanks in advance.

private fun startPayment() {

```
    val activity: Activity = requireActivity()
    val co = Checkout()
    try {
        val options = JSONObject()
        options.put("name", "Vendor")
        options.put("description", " for Order")
        //You can omit the image option to fetch the image from dashboard
        options.put("image", "https://rzp-mobile.s3.amazonaws.com/images/rzp.png")
        options.put("currency", "INR")
        val payment: String = "1"//getcart?.CartTotal.toString()
        // amount is in paise so please multiple it by 100
        //Payment failed Invalid amount (should be passed in integer paise. Minimum value is 100 paise, i.e. ₹ 1)
        var total = payment.toDouble()
        total = total * 100
        options.put("amount", total)
        val preFill = JSONObject()
        preFill.put("email", "hell@gmail.com")
        preFill.put("contact", "9898989898")
        options.put("prefill", preFill)
        co.open(requireActivity(), options)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in payment: " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onPaymentSuccess(s: String?) {
    toast("onPaymentSuccess")
    Log.i(TAG, "onPaymentSuccess: $s")
}

override fun onPaymentError(i: Int, s: String?) {
    Log.e(TAG,  "error code "+i.toString()+" -- Payment failed "+s.toString())
    try {
        toast("Payment error please try again")
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        Log.e("OnPaymentError", "Exception in onPaymentError", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share you code

Comment: please check @RajendraMahato above code is edited

Comment: Have you added Checkout.preload(getApplicationContext()); in your coCreate method? btw your code is looking good, it should work. Please share some logs as well

Comment: Do one thing start this payment flow in an activity instead of fragment. I can remember, I was facing the same issue

Comment: yes Checkout.preload(getApplicationContext()) added ...this is for faster load razorpay screen

Comment: yeah while am using in activity is working fine but my question is I need to integrate while using in fragment

Comment: this issue is from razor pay side, we can not do anything. But if you tell me what you what to achieve and your fragment flow then I can suggest you some alternate way

Comment: make a separate payment activity and from that fragment start the payment activity using startActivityForResult and then nonsuccess or failure set the result.

Comment: thanks for suggestion bro @RajendraMahato

Comment: I got solution I think

Comment: Note: 
If you are calling the payment start method from inside a fragment, ensure that the fragment's parent activity implements the PaymentResultListener interface.

Comment: now how we will get Parent activity interface listener to fragment can u please give any suggestion bro @RajendraMahato

Comment: ok wait I have a better solution

Comment: do all payment related things in the payment activity and implement PaymentResultListener also in the same activity. You just need to pass amount in paise from fragment to the payment activity. By using this technique, in future you can reuse this payment activity anywhere

Comment: if you are still confused then do let me know, will send you code example by tonight.

Comment: thank u so much for support...will try if I didn't will getback to u

Answer (score 1):

1. Amount should be in Integer and in paise.
2. implement result listener to the fragment host activity and override error and success function there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30067972)

Answer (score 0):

in fragment you won't get Razorpay callback function, so you should implement  PaymentResultListener or PaymentResultWithDataListener in activity and from activity you have call your fragment and do your api call for razor pay response.

in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onPaymentSuccess(String s, PaymentData paymentData) {
    try {
        FeeFragment feeList = (FeeFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        feeList.checkRazorResponse(paymentData, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception in success", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in your Fragment:

```
public void checkRazorResponse(PaymentData paymentData, boolean success) {
    if (success) {
        updatePaymentStatus(paymentData);
        //do your api call
    } else {
        //handle error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Razorpay payment integration is not supported on the fragment. You have to implement it on Activity.
Like this way

This code is for fragment:

```
binding.tvPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is for Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityPaymentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    payOnline()
}

private fun payOnline() {
    val checkout = Checkout()
    checkout.setKeyID(getString(R.string.razorpay_api_key))
    checkout.setImage(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    try {
        val options = JSONObject()
        options.put("name", "mName")
        options.put("currency", "INR")
        options.put("image", R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        options.put("amount", 10000) //pass amount in currency subunits
        options.put("prefill.email", "roydeveloper01@gmail.com")
        options.put("prefill.contact", "8620828385")
        checkout.open(this, options)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in starting Razorpay Checkout: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

override fun onPaymentSuccess(p0: String?) {
    try {
        binding.tvId.text = "Payment Successful \n Transaction ID $p0"
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        binding.tvId.text ="Exception"
    }
}

override fun onPaymentError(p0: Int, p1: String?) {
    try {
        binding.tvId.text ="Exception: $p1"
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    binding.tvId.text ="Error: $p1"

}
```

My problem is solved this way. I think your problem will also solve . Best of luck.